# Xcode Swift terminal application - Unable to debug

Tags: xcode, macos, swift3, xcode8

Swift 3.0.2, Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)

Project was created using Swift Package Manager `swift package init`

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Collection",
    dependencies: [
      .Package(url: "https://github.com/czechboy0/Jay.git", majorVersion: 1),
      .Package(url: "https://github.com/Zewo/HTTPClient.git", majorVersion: 0, minor: 14),
      .Package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/HeliumLogger.git", majorVersion: 1)
    ]
)
```

This is a terminal OS X / Linux application

```
✗ find Sources
Sources
Sources/Collection
Sources/Collection/.DS_Store
...
Sources/Collection/main.swift
...
```

Xcode project was created with `swift package generate-xcodeproj`

Regardless of if it's a first launch of the project in Xcode or subsequent builds, setting a breakpoint works but renders the debugging support support completely useless.

- Watch symbols are not displayed.
- po / p instructions do not work

Xcode embedded debugging terminal shows this on project breakpoint:

```
warning: Swift error in module Collection.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module POSIX.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module Axis.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module Venice.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module HTTP.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module File.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module HTTPFile.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module IP.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module OpenSSL.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module TCP.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module HTTPClient.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

Shared Swift state for Collection has developed fatal errors and is being discarded.
REPL definitions and persistent names/types will be lost.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- open terminal
- type `sudo xcode-select -r`

`xcode-select -r` resets the path to:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

The old one was:
`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Comment: This seems to be the most plausible cause, I'm accepting this answer without being able to confirm that it is indeed solves the issue. Thank you for the idea. For me installing the beta of Xcode 8.3 // Version 8.3 beta 2 (8W120l) resolved it, without being able to figure out the root cause.

Comment: I removed completely the CommandLineTools, because of legacy code issue. Xcode alone works better.

Comment: Thanks this fixed my issue!